# Is it wrong to import an sql file like this?

Tags: mysql, database, sql

I was trying to import the the known database "northwind" to my workbench via mysql command line. I just copy-paste the database and it seemed to be working.
I execute the command 'show databases' and it is shown in the list of databases.
mysql> USE northwind

everything seems to be fine, however when working from the workbench, I can notice some information missing. for example in table 'orders' I have 'EmployeeId' field I can see that there total 9 employees(9 id'S in total,for many orders),but in table 'employees' I noticed only 4 employees ranging 1-4 Id, thus making me wonder if my way of importing the database is maybe not so conventional...? please how can I solve this?